# How do I implement a (read ) function into Scheme?

Tags: io, scheme

I would like to implement a user input (read) in scheme so there are three variables (x y n). I tried to implement it but it only takes the first digit for example if I were to input (10 5 2) it will only take (10). So I am wondering how I can implement the Read Function that will allow me to take 3 integers from the user and set them as the (x y n) variables so I can run the Division function below, which is basically, X divided by Y N number of times.

```
(display "Enter 10 5 2 as test case.")
(newline)
(define ReadForDivide (Read))
(display ReadForDivide)
;10

(define (nDivide x y n) 
  (if (= n 0)
      x
     (nDivide (Divide x y) y (- n 1))))
```

Comment: Show how you're trying to use `(read)` with this?

Comment: Call `(read)` 3 times, once for each variable.

Comment: If the user enters `(10 5 2)` you can use `apply` to pass all of them as arguments to the function.

Comment: Implement or *use*?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple `prompt` procedure that takes a message and a sentinel value as inputs, and recursively collects user input until the sentinel value is entered. A list of the input values is returned when the sentinel value is encountered in the input:

```
(define (prompt msg sentinel)
  (display sentinel) (display " to finish") (newline)
  (display msg)
  (let ((user-input (read)))
    (if (equal? user-input sentinel)
        '()
        (cons user-input (prompt msg sentinel)))))
```

You could use the same idea to write an even simpler procedure that takes a message and a count of the number of inputs required, returning a list of those inputs. Maybe the first procedure should be called `prompt-sentinel` and the second `prompt-count`. I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.

Sample interaction:

```
> (apply + (prompt "Enter a number: " 'q))
q to finish
Enter a number: 1
q to finish
Enter a number: 2
q to finish
Enter a number: 3
q to finish
Enter a number: q
6
```

Note that a symbol (or any object) passed as the sentinel value must be entered unquoted by the user:

```
> (prompt "Enter a number: " 'oops)
oops to finish
Enter a number: 1
oops to finish
Enter a number: 2
oops to finish
Enter a number: 3
oops to finish
Enter a number: 'oops
oops to finish
Enter a number: oops
(1 2 3 'oops)
```